# How to obtain and clear states for Angular

Tags: angular

I have a scenario where I perform a route jump (equivalent to refreshing) on the same page, but the jump will bring state data. However, although the state carries data, I can only obtain it through history and cannot clear it. Is there any way for Regular to set, obtain, or clear it?

```
   async refresh() {
    // Equivalent to jumping in place
    this.router.navigateByUrl('form',{
      state: {
        name: 'jack',
        age: 252
      },
    })
  }
```

I can obtain the state through getCurrentNavigation, but it will not trigger again in the constructor after refreshing

```
   ngDoCheck(): void {
    // this.init(this.router);
    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation() 
    const extras = navigation?.extras;
    const state = extras?.state;
    console.log(navigation,'navigation');
    console.log(state,'state');
    console.log('ngDoCheck')
  }
```

So I tried to obtain it in the DoCheck lifecycle, but at this point there is no router object and the acquisition is undefined`

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

What about navigating an extra time to clear the state?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="refresh()">Refresh</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  async refresh() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('form', {
      state: {
        name: 'jack',
        age: 252,
      },
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(() => {
        const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
        console.log('NavigationEnd', navigation?.extras.state);
        if (navigation?.extras.state?.name) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('form', {
            onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
          });
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: ngDoCheck
AfterContentChecked
AfterViewChecked
Adding this attribute still only triggers these hook functions

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You need to call getCurrentNavigation during navigation, it's too late inside those life cycle methods.
https://angular.io/api/router/Router#getcurrentnavigation

Comment: My scenario is as follows: I have a route called localhost: 8080/form, and the page is already displayed. Then, on this route page, there is a button that will redirect to the original location, This. router. navigateByUrl ('form ', {state: {name:'jack', age: 252,}) is only a data state carried by the in situ transfer. However, after the in situ transfer, Oninit will not be triggered, so getCurrentNavigation in the router is undefined. Your example above can only obtain the value for the first time, and cannot obtain it afterwards unless history is used, but this is not what I expected

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to router.events in your original location?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it? Do I understand this aspect very well? I have tried this writing method: this. router. events. subscribe (e=>{})